# Regarding Visual Studio shortcut for eg cw for console.writeline and alt button for selecting access modifiers

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Are there more visual studio shortcuts such as `cw` for console.writeline and alt button for selecting access modifiers?

---

There might be many more shortcut keys which I don't know can anyone provide me with the entire list for the same or give me some link or idea how to do so.

For eg ,

Class ABC
{
Public int ID,
Public String name,
Public String  Place,
Public int Phone,
Public int Salary
}

So in above code if we press alt and select we can select Public throughout the code and change Public to Private.

So like this I want to know more or all the Visual studio shortcuts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are called [Code Snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-snippets?view=vs-2022). See the documentation to learn about more of them.